# woocommerce main content of page doesn't change in width

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have tried a couple of approaches to extend the main content of my woocommerce page to take up the full width of the screen (or like 98%).

However, my CSS is having no effect. I have tried the below code:

```
div#content-area {
    width: 100%!important;
    margin: 0!important;
}

div.container {
    padding: 0!important;
}
```

It more or less looks like the below screenshot:

[image]

When I want it to look like this:

[image]

Any ideas on what I'm missing here?

Comment: We may need to see the HTML code as well. Can you post a demo or at least a link/

Comment: Yeah I’ll post a demo that’s going to be a lot of code